# Set the selected value of a select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select list:

```
<select id="one" class="sel">
    <option id="1">1</option>
    <option id="2">2</option>
    <option id="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="two" class="sel">
    <option id="1">1</option>
    <option id="2">2</option>
    <option id="3">3</option>
</select>
```

and span:

```
<span id="three">set three</span>
```

i would like click on this span and should in two list select (id one and two) be option id=3 selected.
How can i make it?

```
$("#three").click(function(){
    $(".sel") ... ????
})
```

**LIVE:** http://jsfiddle.net/rUbGx/

btw. i would like example with ID in option, not with value. Thanks.

Comment: look, we understand that you _also_ have `value` attributes, but you really shouldn't misuse `id` instead - use a `data-xxx` element.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: You have duplicate ID in the same html. It will work and getElementById will return you an array of matching ID's, but ID's are supposed to be unique.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id on your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attribute selector.

```
$("#three").click(function(){
    $(".sel").find('[id=3]').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rUbGx/9/)

Comment: This works, but you should have mentioned that id must be unique.

Comment: @TonioElGringo - You are right, the id's should in unique on a page. Since we limiting the scope to find the element it will work in this answer.

Comment: yes, that is why it works, but that doesn't mean it is the best way to do it. Using the same code and replacing id by data-xxx as mentioned by Alnitak would be much nicer and work just as well.

Comment: No where I have mentioned it is the best way to do. This answer is as per OP's markup and if required OP can change the attribute name and use it accordingly. The main point is how to use `jQuery` api to find the required element with matching attribute value. Your downvote is completely senseless.

Answer (score 3):

Change `id` to `value` in `option`s, then:

```
$("#three").click(function(){
    $(".sel").val(3);
});
```

Also see your updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rUbGx/5/).

Comment: This solution will not work. OP has not used `value` attribute for option elements. Care to modify your answer?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, you don't even need to change the `id` to `value`. http://jsfiddle.net/Qrbs2/

Comment: You are basically setting the value of the select element to 3. That is why you think it is working.

Comment: @primatology: And id's must start with a letter, never a number.

Comment: OP does not intend to use value, so I think this would not solve the problem.

Comment: @TonioElGringo: But the `id`s he is using are not html valid, so he can't change both `select`s at once, because `id`s have to be unique; so the normal way is to use `value`.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, that's incorrect. jQuery's val method will select the `option` with a matching innerHTML if the `value` attribute is missing. See last example: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: @scessor, yes, the *option* IDs are invalid. But that fortunately doesn't matter, since the select IDs are valid (and we're selecting those with by class, anyway).

Comment: @scessor You can see ShankarSangoli's answer to get how you can actually change both selects at once with only id (I don't mean that giving the same id to 2 elements is good, it's really not). The question was not "What is the normal way to change selected option with jquery", but it specified not to use value (I think OP did realize that jquery had a method val...).

Comment: @TonioElGringo, ah, that's a good call. Poorly phrased on his part, but that makes sense. (Though if he's merely using IDs as indices, Esalija's solution is ideal.)

Comment: @primatology - That still doesn't answer the OP's question. OP wants to select the option with id = 3. What if the innerHTML do not match with the id attribute?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, I see that now. IDs are a poor solution, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function.

```
$("#three").click(function(){
    $(".sel").val("3");
})
```

---

Everyone who thinks you need to set a value on the `option`: you don't. Look at the jQuery core:

```
option: {
            get: function( elem ) {
                var val = elem.attributes.value;
                return !val || val.specified ? elem.value : elem.text;
            }
        },
```

If there's no value attribute, the text of `option` is used instead. Thus, calling `val(3)` will search for an option with a text value of "3", and select the appropriate element. That the IDs aren't unique is irrelevant.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qrbs2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#three").click(function(){
    $(".sel").prop( "selectedIndex", 2 );
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rUbGx/3/

Comment: This will not check for the attribute id = 3 which is required by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Just did this one for fun.. Check my [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/rUbGx/10/) here

```
var txt2Num = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five','six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
$("#three").click(function(){
    var textNum = $.trim($(this).text()).replace('set ', '');
    var selectedIndex = $.inArray(textNum, txt2Num);   

    $(".sel").each (function (index) {       
        this.selectedIndex = selectedIndex - 1;
    });
});
```